# Problemas con windows update sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, windows-server

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan prestar.
Tengo una máquina virtual Windows Server 2016 y tiene instalado SQL server 2016, el problema se presenta al correr el Windows update siempre me muestra que esta pendiente la actualización Security Update for SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 1 GDR (KB4019089), pero al instalarla se demora un rato y luego aparece el mensaje

> Security Update for SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 1 GDR (KB4019089) -
>   Error 0x80070643

Me podrían ayudar como quito esta actualización para que Windows no la siga tratando de ejecutar??

Answer (score 0):

Si SQL Server 2016 tiene instalado el SP1, esta actualización debe ejecutar sin problema. Ejecuta en el SQL Server Management Studio el comando T-SQL SELECT @@VERSION para validar esto. Si el número de versión es inferior a 13.0.4001.0, entonces aplica primero el SP1, el cual puedes descargar en [Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 1 (SP1)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54276). Luego si aplicas el GDR.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, al consultar la versión aparece

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4019089) - 13.0.4206.0 (X64)   Jul  6 2017 07:55:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Gracias por el dato. Ahí con lo que compartes, tienes dicha actualización, pero no comprendo porque Microsoft Update solicita esa misma. Sugiero montar esta actualización para ese SQL Server 2016, a ver si eso le indica a Microsoft Update que no la solicite: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057118.